# Changing the owner of file in Windows isn't working

Tags: windows-7

So I recently re-installed Windows to fix some driver problems I have been having, and now the drive that I was storing all of my files on (A different drive not the one Windows is installed on) won't let me access any of the files with an *Access Denied: Please contact the owner* Error. so I ran

```
takeown /F Drive /R /D Y
```

on the drive and it ran without errors, however it is still giving me the error, so I have no Idea...

Answer (score 2):

Apparently owning a file in windows doesn't give one permission to do anything to it...

adding myself using icacls with full control:

```
icacls [drive]:\* /T /grant [username]:F
```

Worked out....

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've figured it out yourself, but I'll provide a little more information on how NTFS access control lists (ACLs) work.

Local administrators have `SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege`, which allows them to forcibly make themselves (or a group they're in) the owner of a securable object. [Read more about privileges at TechNet.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530716(v=vs.85).aspx) Normal users can take ownership if they're granted the right via the object's ACL, but admins can blow through ACLs with that privilege.

The only special thing about being an object's owner is that you can always read and write its ACL, even in the presence of a deny entry for those permissions! (This is where the "discretionary" part of "Discretionary Access Control List" comes from - the owner is responsible for who can do what.)

You had initially taken ownership of the files, which then enabled you to write to their ACLs, which then restored the appropriate access.

Note that programs running as administrator can enable `SeBackupPrivilege` and `SeRestorePrivilege` to read and write anything (respectively), no matter what the ACLs say or who the owner is.